# Error in linking in C using C-free compiler

Tags: c

I'm using `C-Free` compiler for c.  This was my first program after installation.
I have also installed `MinGw`.

Here's my program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

I have this error and I don't know how to solve it.

```
[Error]\mingw\lib\crt2.o:(.text+0x188):undefined refrence to `__dyn_tls_init_callback`
[Error]\mingw\lib\crt2.o:(.text+0x1c6):undefined refrence to `_setargv`
[Error]collect2:ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I think the problem is the libraries path! I think you have to set it! I don't remember how to do that using MinGw under Windows! But you may google for that!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your installation is corrupted. Check if you have MINGW installed twice.